# please let me know the meaning of “Madam Secretary” dialogues

Tags: meaning

Whenever I cannot understand some English expression, I am getting big help from this site. Very useful website and good people.
Anyway. I am watching American Drama "Madam Secretary" season1, episode 15. And there are some dialogues I can't understand. Please help me!
Here is the dialogue.

---

Elizabeth:  Yeah. And he said that Samila Mahdavi is working  for the CIA.

Andrew: And you're thinking Juliet could've been **running**  her.

*(FYI, Samila was dead Iranian Intelligence Agenct and Juliet was CIA agent but betrayed CIA)*

Elizabeth (os): **That's where I've been going with it. As a rogue  asset.** Is that even possible?

Andrew: **At this point?** (scoffs)

Elizabeth:  **That's what I was afraid of.** He also said something  about Mahdavi being involved in a plot against the  Iranian government. I mean... Do you think that  that's what this whole thing could be about?

I can understand roughly but I need to know what the sentences meaning exactly. I am very appreciate if somebody who watched this drama help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Andrew: And you're thinking Juliet could've been **running** her.
> [And you're thinking that Juliet could have been using her as a spy.]
>
> Elizabeth (os): **That's where I've been going with it.**
> [That's what I've been thinking.]
> Elizabeth: **As a rogue asset.** Is that even possible?
> [As an unofficial spy in unapproved operations]
>
> Andrew: **At this point?** (scoffs)
> [Given what we know about the current circumstances?]
>
> Elizabeth: **That's what I was afraid of**.
> [From what you say, what I was worried might happen appears to be the case]

(Fair warning:  I haven't watched the program.)